# How can I make or render a website with wiki features(for e.g wikipedia) with Drupal?

Tags: theming, nodes, features

The question is can I render wiki features in my website which is to be made with Drupal.For e.g if I make a website with tons of features how can Wiki feature be made functional with Drupal.If no should I make new themes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To allow contributors to easily link between multiple pages, check out the [Freelinking module](http://drupal.org/project/freelinking).

To enable simple plain-text formatting, check out the [Markdown module](http://drupal.org/project/markdown).

To allow editing subsections of text individually, check out the [Edit Section module](http://drupal.org/project/edit_section).

To automatically generate a Table of Contents for each node, check out the [Table of Contents module](http://drupal.org/project/tableofcontents).

To move comments to a separate page (similar to the Wikipedia "Talk" pages), check out the [Talk module](http://drupal.org/project/talk).

Comment: +1 I am looking for the same as OP, so this helped somewhat. BUT, (disclaimer: I am a Druapl n00b and don't even have my first site yet), while Freelinking will let a user link to existing pages, it does not seem to allow to to create a new page.  I am not sure about OP, but I want something like http://my_site.com/wiki with all the wiki pages under that and editable/creatable by any registered user.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Mawg: Freelinking lets the site admin choose how to handle links to pages that don't exist.  From the Freelinking README.TXT:  "If no node so titled exists, the link will attempt to create the node and present the user with the node creation form, with the title already filled in."

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/wikitools ?
Drupal have a native [revision](http://drupal.org/node/320614) system, so this is an essential part of a wiki.
Can you describe a little more what kind of features you're expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar project and I make use of following combination

1. Installed the profile [Corporative Site](http://drupal.org/project/corporative_site), as it contains the the rich text editor - "[CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor)" and the image upload option with [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) preconfigured.
2. Enabled the "book" module which is a part of drupal core from *admin/modules*, as it contains the most of the wiki features by default.
3. Installed [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) and [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) to give appropriate access to the types of users like - Administrator, Author(The one who will be responsible to add a book page), and Authenticated user(will just see the page and comment.
4. And created a sub-theme by following [this](http://drupal.org/node/225125) procedure.